# How to sort data in stored procedure with column positions of select statement with CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is not working

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN @OrderBy = 'EndDateInDays' AND @OrderByDirection = 'D' 
          THEN 10 
    END DESC,
    CASE 
       WHEN @OrderBy = 'EndDateInDays' AND @OrderByDirection != 'D' 
          THEN 10 
    END
```

Where this one is working

```
ORDER BY 10 DESC
```

Comment: I have looked at http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1276352&seqNum=4 but using all these it won't help any more

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER

Comment: Yes the column position of select statement in my Query

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to use the column number instead of the column name?  Are the columns dynamic?

Comment: 'code'  SELECT 
          Id
   ,(CASE WHEN UFF.[Id] IS NULL THEN CONVERT(BIT, 0) ELSE CONVERT(BIT, 1) END) AS Favourite 
   ,F.[Agent]
   ,F.Name AS Name
       ,CONVERT(Datetime, F.[Date] , 103) AS DatePublished
   ,UF.[ToolTip]
   ,F.[CreationDate]

Comment: yes that column is dynamic

Comment: The first query makes no sense. The second one means "order by result-set column number 10". (I.e. the since long deprecated order by ordinal position.)

Comment: I have few cases for sorting my data, where in one case i need to sort data by a dynamic column. if i am using position of the element it is not sorting the data as excepted. Please let me know is there any thing to do with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation,

```sql
ORDER BY order_by_expression
```

> *order_by_expression* Specifies a **column or expression** on which to sort
>   the query result set. A sort column can be specified as a name or
>   column alias, or a nonnegative integer representing the position of
>   the column in the select list.

Source: [SELECT - ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql)

You are specifying an expression, hence the SQL Server does not sort by value in column #10. Instead it sorts your rows by a constant value '10', which results in no sort being performed.

### Suggested solution

Move all complex columns into a CROSS APPLY sub-query and add another CROSS APPLY with a sorting column:

```sql
SELECT  F.Id
        ,cols.Favourite
        ,F.Agent
        ,F.Name
        ,cols.DatePublished
        ,UF.ToolTip
        ,F.CreationDate
FROM MyTable F
  INNER JOIN MyTable2 UF
    ON f.Id = UF.Id
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT       (CASE WHEN UFF.[Id] IS NULL THEN CONVERT(BIT, 0) ELSE CONVERT(BIT, 1) END) AS Favourite
              ,CONVERT(Datetime, F.[Date] , 103) AS DatePublished
) cols
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT         -- Make sure to correctly cast all numeric and date values to text
               CASE WHEN    @OrderBy = 'EndDateInDays' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), F.[EndDateDate], 126)
                    WHEN    @OrderBy = 'Name' THEN F.Name
                    WHEN    @OrderBy = 'DatePublished' THEN cols.DatePublished
                    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), F.Id) -- This is default sort
                  END AS [SortCol]

) sort
ORDER BY 
         CASE WHEN @OrderByDirection = 'D' THEN sort.[SortCol] END DESC
        ,CASE WHEN @OrderByDirection != 'D' THEN sort.[SortCol] END
;
```

Comment: Yes that make sense, Is there any way to implement this type of queries

Comment: @Sowjanya, I revised the answer to include a suggested solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the column alias.  Let's say it is `EndDateInDays`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'EndDateInDays' AND @OrderByDirection = 'D' 
               THEN EndDateInDays
          END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'EndDateInDays' AND @OrderByDirection <> 'D' 
               THEN EndDateInDays 
          END)
```

If `EndDateInDays` is a number (as suggested by the name), you could do:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'EndDateInDays' AND @OrderByDirection = 'D' 
               THEN - EndDateInDays
               WHEN @OrderBy = 'EndDateInDays' AND @OrderByDirection <> 'D' 
               THEN EndDateInDays 
          END)
```

Also, be careful if you start combining multiple columns.  It is better to have a separate `CASE` expression for each column to prevent inadvertent type mismatching.

Comment: Thank you for your update,Here EndDateInDays is Alias name of my dynamic column, if i am using that it is always giving following error  Invalid column name 'EndDateInDays'.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_GetItems, Line 110
Invalid column name 'EndDateInDays'.  I am getting this error